# Reusing workspace across multiple nodes in parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have parallel stages setup in my Jenkins pipeline script which execute tests on separate nodes (AWS EC2 instances)

e.g.

```
stage('E2E-PR') {
    parallel {
        stage('Cypress Tests 1') {
            agent { label 'aws_slave_cypress' }
            steps {
                runE2eTests()
            }
        }
        stage('Cypress Tests 2') {
            agent { label 'aws_slave_cypress' }
            steps {
                runE2eTests()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to re-use the checked out repo\generated workspace generated from the parent node used at the start of my pipeline rather than each parallel stage checking out it's own copy.

I came across an approach using sequential stages, and nesting stages within stages to share workspaces across multiple stages, which I tried like below

```
parallel {
    stage('Cypress Tests') {
        agent { label 'aws_slave_cypress' }
        stages {
            stage('Cypress 1') {
                steps {
                    runE2eTests()
                }
            }
            stage('Cypress 2') {
                steps {
                    runE2eTests()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can see from my Jenkins build output that only one aws instance gets spun up and used for both of my nested stages which doesnt give me the benefit of parallelism.

I have also come across the stash\unstash commands, but I have read these should be used for small files and not for large directories\entire repositories?

What's the right approach here to allow me to have parallel stages across multiple nodes use the same originally generated workspace? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about why you'd like to do this? (Shallowly) cloning a git repo isn't that different from stashing and unstashing the files.

Comment: So the slave agents used for the tests, just need to be able to reference some test files, so I could use stash\unstash approach thinking about it some more.

Answer (score 6):

I can share a bit information on a similar situation we have in our company:
We have an automation regression suite for UI testing that needs to be executed on several different machines (Win32,Win64, Mac and more). The suite configuration is controlled by a config file that contains all relevant environment parameters and URLs.
The Job allows a user to select the suites that will be executed (and the git branch), select labels (agents) that the suites will be executed on, and select the environment configuration that those suites will use.

How does the flow look like:

1. Generate the config file according to the user input and save (stash) it.
2. In parallel for all given labels: clone the suites repository using shallow clone -> copy the configuration file (unsatsh) -> run the tests -> save (stash) the output of the tests.
3. Collect the outputs of all tests (unstash), combine them into a single report, publish the report and notify users.

The pipeline itself (simplified) will look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
         extendedChoice(name: 'Agents', ...)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Create Config') {
            steps {
                // create the config file called config.yaml
                ...
                stash name: 'config' , includes: 'config.yaml'
            }
        }
        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel params.Agents.collectEntries { agent ->
                        ["Running on ${agent}": {
                            stage(agent) {
                                node(agent) {
                                    println "Executing regression tests on ${agent}"
                                    stage('Clone Tests') {
                                        // Git - shallow clone the automation tests
                                    }
                                    stage('Update Config') {
                                        unstash 'config'
                                    }
                                    stage('Run Suite') {
                                        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                            // Run the tests
                                        }
                                    }
                                    stage('Stash Results'){
                                        stash name: agent , includes: 'results.json'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Combine and Publish Report') {
            steps {
                // Unstash all results from each agent to the same folder
                params.Agents.each { agent ->
                    dir(agent){
                        unstash agent
                    }
                }
                // Run command to combine the results and generated the HTML report
                // Use publishHTML to publish the HTML report to Jenkins
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        // Notify users
    }
}
```

So as you can see for handling relatively small files like the config files and the test result files (which are less the 1M) `stash` and `unstash` are quick and very easy to use and offer great flexibility, but when you use them for bigger files, then they start to overload the system.
Regarding the tests themself, eventually you must copy the files to each workspace in the different agents, and shallow cloning them from the repository is probably the most efficient and easy to use method if your tests are not packaged.

If your tests can easily be packaged, like a python package for example then you can create a different CI pipeline that will archive them as a package for each code change, and then your automation pipeline can use them with tools like pip or so and avoid the need to clone the repository.
That is also true when you run your tests in a container, as you can create a CI that will prepare an image that already contains the tests and then just use that image in the pipeline without need for cloning it agin.
If your Git sever is somewhat very slow you can always package the tests in your CI using zip or a similar archiver, upload them to S3 (using [aws-steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/)) or equivalent and download them during the automation pipeline execution - but in most cases this will not offer any performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to send generated files to s3 on post step for example. Download these files on the first step of your pipeline.

Think about storage, which you need to share between jenkins agents.